# Collectd with CSV output

Tags: collectd

I have installed Collectd on Linux Ubuntu and I added plugin for CSV output in collectd.conf file, I am getting 2 column values in the csv ,but as there is no column name specifically, could someone et me know what values it is importing and is it possible to format the csv as we wish.

Answer (score 1):

The first column is the timestamp in epoch, the second column is the value collectd is reporting - the value depends on the CSV file you're looking at, like cpu-user, memory-free, etc

Answer (score 0):

you can see folders hierarchy, like  **user>cpu-0>cpu-idle-date** from this cpu-idle-date you can see epoch and values here.

This means now you are opening csv files from cpu-idle data in cpu folders created by collectd.